# Sort table based on visit count and weighted based on datetime

Tags: sql-server, sorting

I want to sort the SQL Server table based on the following order:

1. Most visited records that inserted in the last seven days come first
2. Then all records that inserted before the last seven days come by visit count desc.

Sample Data:

```
Id | Title | CreatedOn   | VisitCount
1  | One   | 2020-04-20  | 51
2  | Two   | 2020-04-22  | 101
3  | Three | 2020-04-25  | 30
4  | Four  | 2020-04-27  | 25
5  | Five  | 2020-04-29  | 30
6  | Six   | 2020-04-30  | 42
7  | Seven | 2020-05-01  | 15
```

Expected result **by supposing that current day is 2020-05-02**

```
Id | Title | CreatedOn   | VisitCount
6  | Six   | 2020-04-30  | 42
5  | Five  | 2020-04-29  | 30
7  | Seven | 2020-05-01  | 15
2  | Two   | 2020-04-22  | 101
1  | One   | 2020-04-20  | 51
3  | Three | 2020-04-25  | 30
4  | Four  | 2020-04-27  | 25
```

How can I complete this query

```
SELECT Id, Title, CreatedOn, VisitCount FROM Posts
ORDER BY .........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a two-tier order by clause:

```
SELECT Id, Title, CreatedOn, VisitCount
FROM Posts
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, CreatedOn, GETDATE()) < 7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    VisitCount DESC;
```